# How can I know my job number when I executing a COBOL program through a shell script

Tags: bash

How can I know my job number when executing a COBOL program through a shell script?

Comment: What shell are you using? Also an an example of how you start the script and what the script contents are could help.

Comment: @Anthon - looks like Bash basead on the tag.

Comment: @slm - Duh, I normally only forget to look at the title of a post... %-)

Comment: @Anthon - I often miss them too 8-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain a little bit more what you're doing? There are several "numbers" related to your program.

**NOTE:** In my examples the dollar sign (`$`) denotes the command prompt and isn't meant to be typed as part of the command.

1. Process ID

   When a program runs in Unix it's assigned a process ID. Say I have the program `sleep`, and I run it for 100 seconds.

   ```
   $ sleep 10000
   ```

   I can then find out its process ID using the command `ps`. The process ID would be `9263`, for example:

   ```
   $ ps -eaf|grep sleep
   saml      9263  5736  0 05:48 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 10000
   ```
2. Backgrounded job

   When a program is backgrounded, it can continue running without being directly connected to the shell from where it was executed.

   ```
   $ sleep 10000 &
   [1] 9370
   ```

   Here I'm runnning the program `sleep` for 10000 seconds. The ampersand (`&`) at the end tells the shell to background it. When jobs are backgrounded they'reassigned a job #. In this case it was assigned job # 1. The `9370` is the process ID.

   We can find out what jobs are running using the `jobs` command:

   ```
   $ jobs
   [1]+  Running                 sleep 10000 &
   ```

   We can use the job # to act on this process either by killing it, or bringing it back into the foreground.

   ```
   $ kill %1

   $ fg
   -or-
   $ fg %1
   ```
3. at and batch commands

   There are additional places where "numbers" show up in a job # capacity. Scheduled tasks that are queued up using the commands `at` or `batch` are also assigned numbers.

   ```
   $ at -f mycrontest.sh  10pm tomorrow
   job 14 at Sun Jul  8 22:00:00 2007
   ```
4. Compute clustering technologies

   Further still, if you're site is using a clustering technology such as [Grid Scheduler/Grid Engine](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/), [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/), or [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cluster_software), these systems too have job #'s assigned to each individual task.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

cobol_program &
echo "The COBOL program is running in the background with PID: $!"
```

See the `man` page for `bash` under 'Special Parameters'